# MVC Add migration to existing migration file

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to apply the changes to the existing migration file? Every time I do the `add-migration some_name_here`, it creates a new file. My migration folder gets very overcrowded making fixing hard. Thanks for the help and ideas.

Comment: Here is what we do: https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks. helped me a lot